# Extract Image DCT matrix and insert into png

Tags: python, image, image-processing, compression, dct

After reading an article on [medium](https://medium.com/@jmperezperez/more-examples-of-progressive-image-loading-f258be9f440b) about progressive image loading I saw an example from clicktorelease.com where it extracts the dct matrix from an image and then injects it into a png image that it's inserted into browser canvas.

I tried to generate the same dct matrix in python following the following steps but I don't get any image.

1. Read image using cv2
2. Splitting into 16x16 blocks
3. Apply DCT on every block
4. Do the zig-zag scan

And I got stuck.
Some ideas: Resize. Do quantization before the zig-zag scan. Reasemble the blocks?

I have the following code in jupyter notebook (it doesn't work):
http://dpaste.com/3DVZ0CN